# Would it be a good idea to mix brown sugar with white sugar in bread?

Tags: bread, sugar, brown-sugar

I was curious, but would the brown sugar feed the yeast and if I mix both of them would it be a good idea? So I can get the benefits of both sugars. If I were to mix what effect would I get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brown sugar is equivalent to sugar plus molasses. If you mix brown sugar and (white) sugar, you'll get slightly brown sugar. Any benefits you were expecting from the (white) sugar, you'll still get. Any benefits you were expecting from the molasses, you'll get less of.